# Problema com vetor de float

Tags: c, struct, array, float

Criei um código para um exercício da faculdade que estava rodando certinho, porém, esqueci que uma das variáveis da `struct` era um vetor, e quando fiz uma simples alteração tudo mudou. Praticamente todas as funções estão dando erro. Não acho a resposta em lugar nenhum.

ANTES (quando funcionava) estava assim:

```
struct turma{
  int matricula;
  char nome[15];
  float nota;
  float media;
  char resultado;
}; typedef struct turma turma;
```

Depois alterei para:

```
struct turma{
  int matricula;
  char nome[15];
  float nota[5];
  float media;
  char resultado;
}; typedef struct turma turma;
```

E não funciona mais nada. Segue o exemplo de uma função que passou a dar erro:

```
void insere (turma alg[MAX])
{   int x,y;
float cont=0;
for (x=0;x<MAX;x++)
{   printf("\nInforme os dados do %iº aluno: ", x+1);
    printf("\n\nMatrícula: ", x+1);
    scanf("%d", &alg[x].matricula);
    printf("Nome: ", x+1);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &alg[x].nome);
        for (y=0;y<5;y++){
        printf("%iº nota: ", y+1);
        scanf("%f", &alg[y].nota);
        cont = cont + alg[y].nota;
    }
}
}
```

O erro da última linha é error:

> invalid operands to binary + (have 'float' and 'float *')

Comment: Você pode adicionar o erro no código **Citação**, para enfatizar sobre o real problema. Adicione também os outros códigos no inicio do post  em `code`, vai destaca-los, ajuda na compreensão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O Problema está que você esta tentando fazer uma soma de uma variavel **float** `(cont)` com um **ponteiro** `(alg[y].nota)`.

Lembre-se que você modificou sua struct para que a variável se tornasse um vetor de float.
Modifique seu trecho de codigo para:

```
scanf("%f", &alg[x].nota[y]);
cont = cont + alg[x].nota[y];
```

Acredito que assim resolverá seu problema